# Auto Forwarding email to assignee based on subject lines in excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub File_Stock_Incoming_Message(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
```

' This macro is called from a wizard-built rule, where the ' rule operates on every incoming message, and its action ' is to call this macro.

```
Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace 
Set NS = Application.Session 
Dim MoveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder 
Set MoveToFolder = NS.Folders("mainboxname").Folders("MsgLog") 
Dim sbjstr As String sbjstr = Item.Subject 
If (sbjstr = "Whatever Site Error") 
Then Item.Move MoveToFolder 
End If 
End Sub
```

I want to edit the above code to forward the email to the specific assignee based on the subject lines and assignee's saved in the excel file.

Comment: Public Sub File_Stock_Incoming_Message(Item As Outlook.MailItem)               
  ' This macro is called from a wizard-built rule, where the
  ' rule operates on *every* incoming message, and its action
  ' is to call this macro.
  Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set NS = Application.Session
  Dim MoveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set MoveToFolder = NS.Folders("mainboxname").Folders("MsgLog")

  Dim sbjstr As String
  sbjstr = Item.Subject
  If (sbjstr = "Whatever Site Error") Then
    Item.Move MoveToFolder
  End If
End Sub

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. [Edit] your original question instead.